# TCL issues with Octal numbers seen after porting from EDK 1.05 to EDK2

Tags: tcl, octal, uefi

I have an EFI Shell tool which uses EDK 1.05 and TCL 8.3 sources. This tool accepts user commands to display PCI-E adapter information and to upgrade firmware on it. I recently ported it to UDK2017. I am using VS2012x86 toolchain to build the tool.

When I run the binary from EFI Shell, TCL reports errors such as these.

```
can't use invalid octal number as operand of "||"
syntax error in expression "(1<<0)"
syntax error in expression "(0x1<<0)"
```

I have read about [TCL and Octal numbers](http://wiki.tcl.tk/498)
Since this issue is not being seen with EDK 1.05 code with the same TCL version, I am wondering if there is any flag I am missing out. I am hoping there is a simple solution to get past this error since there was no change in the TCL version.

Comment: Wow… 8.3 is rather a long time out of support (well over a decade!). Its successor 8.4 is also out of support, and 8.5 is currently on long-term support only. Not your fault, of course, but there's a definite limit…

Answer (score 2):

### Octal Issue

It's hard to be sure, but I suspect with the octal number issue you've got code that's parsing something like `080808` as a number, which is interpreted as octal because of the leading `0` (just like a constant in C or C++) and so can't contain an `8` (or `9`). To parse a number definitely as decimal, the `scan` command is used:

```
set val 080808
scan $val "%d" parsedVal
# Properly, should check that [scan] has a result of 1, but I probably wouldn't bother
puts "$val -> $parsedVal"
```

### Odd Expression Syntax Error

The other `syntax error in expression "(1<<0)"` errors are stranger, as those are *definitely* valid syntax. I've only got versions back to 8.4 on this machine, but…

```
$ tclsh8.4
% expr (1<<0)
1
```

The only ways that could be an invalid expression are if it is either in some custom expression language (which would be application-specific; you'll have to read the documentation to figure that out) or if you're using an expression string as a numeric value:

```
% set val (1<<0)
(1<<0)
% expr {$val + 1}
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
```

but that wouldn't produce exactly the error you are seeing. Very puzzling indeed!

### Use Stack Traces

There is something that might help you figure out what is going on. After an error, the global `errorInfo` variable has a stack trace generated. For example, after the above erroring `expr` it has this:

```
% puts $errorInfo
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
    while executing
"expr {$val + 1}"
```

The good thing is that this tells you exactly what command and where gave you the error; that can make a gigantic difference in your detective work to hunt down your problems.

Comment: Thank you Donal! I have a lot of places where the syntax error is seen. So using scan is a bit difficult. The stack trace is definitely useful.